# Byte array copy to another byte array in c#

Tags: c#, serial-port

This is my code. When i run this first byte is saved in tempbuf's 0th position. But when i got second byte, the first value is cleared in tempbuf :-(

```
private void serialPort1_DataReceived(object sender, System.IO.Ports.SerialDataReceivedEventArgs e)
{
    int bytes = serialPort1.BytesToRead;
    byte[] byte_buffer = new byte[200];
    byte[] tempbuf = new byte[200];
    byte[]tempbuf2=new byte[200];
    byte[] ar = new byte[20];
    byte[] ssd = new byte[4];
    byte[] ctrl = new byte[20];

     string pp = "";
     string ll = "";

     serialPort1.Read(byte_buffer, 0, bytes);



     if (i == 0)
     {
        index = byte_buffer[0];
     }
      tempbuf[q++] = byte_buffer[0];
     i++;
     if (i == 200)
     {

      array[index] = TestSerializer.MarshalToStructureArray(tempbuf, tempbuf.Length);
      if (textBox30.InvokeRequired)
      {

     this.Invoke(((MethodInvoker)delegate
      {
       textBox30.Text = index.ToString();
     }));
    }
    i = 0;
    }
   if (q == 200)
    {


   q = 0;
}
```

Comment: Learn to format your code please.

Comment: Where is `q` defined and what are you using it for? Your variable names are fairly cryptic so it's hard to tell what you're trying to do.

Comment: I will explain in detail. In This program  receiving one byte at a time in byte buffer array. If first byte received is '1',it will be in tempbuf's 'o' th position.
And if second byte received is '2',In tempbufs '0'th position must contain '1' & '1'st position contain '2'.'q' is just a variable for  Incrimenting the position of tempbuff.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved this problem by declaring `tempbuf` as static byte array:

```
static byte[] tempbuf = new byte[200];
```